# Capturing repeated group in Regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capture repeated groups in a PHP regular expression.

The expression I'm using is: `(?:.*\s|^)@\[(\d+)\]`, which would match stuff like:

`some text here @[2] some more text` and return 2 in the matches.

Now I'd like to match:

`some text here @[2] some more text @[3] more text` and return [2, 3]. Right now, I can only get it to return 3 (the last element) with this expression: `(((?:.*\s|^)@\[(\d+)\])+)`.

I've read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) and [this](http://aralbalkan.com/1446), but I couldn't get those working with preg_match or preg_match_all.

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this simpler solution:

```
$string = 'some text here @[2] some more text @[3] more text';
preg_match_all('/@\[(\d+)\]/', $string, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
$result = '[' . implode(', ', $matches) . ']';
echo $result; // [2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I don't know what the @ does though, could you explain this?

Comment: @TimvanDalen Nothing special. I added it just because I thought that you need only the number between '[' and ']' with a '@' first.

Comment: Oh of course, ignore that comment. I thought you used a special operator, I read that as \@. Thank you.